# The existence of cycles in a composed iterated function ad infinitum.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I originally posted this on MathOverflow, but it was deemed not 'research-level'.

The functions I have been concerned with recently are as follows: $\sigma(n^2)$ (divisor function), $P(n)$ (greatest prime factor) and $f(n)= P(\sigma(n^2))$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

When pondering on the subject of taking these as iterated functions ad infinitum, it seems clear that $\sigma(n) \rightarrow \infty$, as the result is always larger than the input.
Similarly, the greatest prime factor immediately or almost immediately reaches a fixed point with convergence to a prime.

Can anyone prove or point me to relevant resources (existing literature) on the most complicated case of the possibility of a periodic point or cycle arising for $f(n)$? I'm stumped. (Although I conjecture that it is impossible)

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: There are really no general techniques for approaching a question like this; when you mix multiplication (via factoring) and addition (via the divisor *sum* function), it turns out that modern mathematics knows very little - so I doubt you'll get a definitive answer. (I mean, this stuff isn't even known about the Collatz map, which appears far simpler) That said, someone might offer a heuristic to suggest this result one way or the other. My computations support this hypothesis, but my computations are limited by the difficulty of factoring large integers.

Comment: I'd like to apologize, I focused on the wrong parts of your question in the mathoverflow thread and didn't understand that this (research-level) question was your point.

Comment: :D Thanks. I'd like to apologise for the rapid and chaotic flurry of edits that followed and the poorly communicated initial post.

Comment: If $q$ is a prime dividing $p^2 + p + 1$ then $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $q$ which means that $q$ is either $2$, $3$, or $1$ mod $6$. A separate argument shows that $f(p)$ is never $2$ or $3$ so $f(p)$ is always $1$ mod $6$ for any prime $p$.